# Create keras callback to save model predictions and targets for each batch during training

Tags: tensorflow, callback, keras

I am building a simple Sequential model in Keras (tensorflow backend). During training I want to inspect the individual training batches and model predictions. Therefore, I am trying to create a custom `Callback` that saves the model predictions and targets for each training batch. However, the model is not using the current batch for prediction, but the entire training data.

How can I hand over only the current training batch to the `Callback`?

And how can I access the batches and targets that the `Callback` saves in self.predhis and self.targets?

My current version looks as follows:

```py
callback_list = [prediction_history((self.x_train, self.y_train))]

self.model.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train, batch_size=self.batch_size, epochs=self.n_epochs, validation_data=(self.x_val, self.y_val), callbacks=callback_list)

class prediction_history(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, train_data):
        self.train_data = train_data
        self.predhis = []
        self.targets = []

    def on_batch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        x_train, y_train = self.train_data
        self.targets.append(y_train)
        prediction = self.model.predict(x_train)
        self.predhis.append(prediction)
        tf.logging.info("Prediction shape: {}".format(prediction.shape))
        tf.logging.info("Targets shape: {}".format(y_train.shape))
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**NOTE**: this answer is outdated and only works with TF1. Check @bers's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59697739) for a solution tested on TF2.

---

After model compilation, the placeholder tensor for `y_true` is in `model.targets` and `y_pred` is in `model.outputs`.

To save the values of these placeholders at each batch, you can:

1. First copy the values of these tensors into variables.
2. Evaluate these variables in `on_batch_end`, and store the resulting arrays.

Now step 1 is a bit involved because you'll have to add an `tf.assign` op to the training function `model.train_function`. Using current Keras API, this can be done by providing a `fetches` argument to `K.function()` when the training function is constructed.

In `model._make_train_function()`, there's a line:

```py
self.train_function = K.function(inputs,
                                 [self.total_loss] + self.metrics_tensors,
                                 updates=updates,
                                 name='train_function',
                                 **self._function_kwargs)
```

The `fetches` argument containing the `tf.assign` ops can be provided via `model._function_kwargs` (only works ***after Keras 2.1.0***).

As an example:

```py
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class CollectOutputAndTarget(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CollectOutputAndTarget, self).__init__()
        self.targets = []  # collect y_true batches
        self.outputs = []  # collect y_pred batches

        # the shape of these 2 variables will change according to batch shape
        # to handle the "last batch", specify `validate_shape=False`
        self.var_y_true = tf.Variable(0., validate_shape=False)
        self.var_y_pred = tf.Variable(0., validate_shape=False)

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        # evaluate the variables and save them into lists
        self.targets.append(K.eval(self.var_y_true))
        self.outputs.append(K.eval(self.var_y_pred))

# build a simple model
# have to compile first for model.targets and model.outputs to be prepared
model = Sequential([Dense(5, input_shape=(10,))])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

# initialize the variables and the `tf.assign` ops
cbk = CollectOutputAndTarget()
fetches = [tf.assign(cbk.var_y_true, model.targets[0], validate_shape=False),
           tf.assign(cbk.var_y_pred, model.outputs[0], validate_shape=False)]
model._function_kwargs = {'fetches': fetches}  # use `model._function_kwargs` if using `Model` instead of `Sequential`

# fit the model and check results
X = np.random.rand(10, 10)
Y = np.random.rand(10, 5)
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=8, callbacks=[cbk])
```

Unless the number of samples can be divided by the batch size, the final batch will have a different size than other batches. So `K.variable()` and `K.update()` can't be used in this case. You'll have to use `tf.Variable(..., validate_shape=False)` and `tf.assign(..., validate_shape=False)` instead.

---

To verify the correctness of the saved arrays, you can add one line in `training.py` to print out the shuffled index array:

```py
if shuffle == 'batch':
    index_array = _batch_shuffle(index_array, batch_size)
elif shuffle:
    np.random.shuffle(index_array)

print('Index array:', repr(index_array))  # Add this line

batches = _make_batches(num_train_samples, batch_size)
```

The shuffled index array should be printed out during fitting:

```
Epoch 1/1
Index array: array([8, 9, 3, 5, 4, 7, 1, 0, 6, 2])
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 23ms/step - loss: 0.5670
```

And you can check if `cbk.targets` is the same as `Y[index_array]`:

```py
index_array = np.array([8, 9, 3, 5, 4, 7, 1, 0, 6, 2])
print(Y[index_array])
[[ 0.75325592  0.64857277  0.1926653   0.7642865   0.38901153]
 [ 0.77567689  0.13573623  0.4902501   0.42897559  0.55825652]
 [ 0.33760938  0.68195038  0.12303088  0.83509441  0.20991668]
 [ 0.98367778  0.61325065  0.28973401  0.28734073  0.93399794]
 [ 0.26097574  0.88219054  0.87951941  0.64887846  0.41996446]
 [ 0.97794604  0.91307569  0.93816428  0.2125808   0.94381495]
 [ 0.74813435  0.08036688  0.38094272  0.83178364  0.16713736]
 [ 0.52609421  0.39218962  0.21022047  0.58569125  0.08012982]
 [ 0.61276627  0.20679494  0.24124858  0.01262245  0.0994412 ]
 [ 0.6026137   0.25620512  0.7398164   0.52558182  0.09955769]]

print(cbk.targets)
[array([[ 0.7532559 ,  0.64857274,  0.19266529,  0.76428652,  0.38901153],
        [ 0.77567691,  0.13573623,  0.49025011,  0.42897558,  0.55825651],
        [ 0.33760938,  0.68195039,  0.12303089,  0.83509439,  0.20991668],
        [ 0.9836778 ,  0.61325067,  0.28973401,  0.28734073,  0.93399793],
        [ 0.26097575,  0.88219053,  0.8795194 ,  0.64887846,  0.41996446],
        [ 0.97794604,  0.91307569,  0.93816429,  0.2125808 ,  0.94381493],
        [ 0.74813437,  0.08036689,  0.38094273,  0.83178365,  0.16713737],
        [ 0.5260942 ,  0.39218962,  0.21022047,  0.58569127,  0.08012982]], dtype=float32),
 array([[ 0.61276627,  0.20679495,  0.24124858,  0.01262245,  0.0994412 ],
        [ 0.60261369,  0.25620511,  0.73981643,  0.52558184,  0.09955769]], dtype=float32)]
```

As you can see, there are two batches in `cbk.targets` (one "full batch" of size 8 and the final batch of size 2), and the row order is the same as `Y[index_array]`.

Comment: But are these really the targets and training batches that are used internally during training? When using it like this, the `y_train` batch has shape `(20,)`. However, when using the `model.fit()` function of Keras and looking inside some metric like accuracy, `y_true` has shape `(TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None)])`

Comment: You're comparing two different things. `y_train` is a numpy array, but `y_true` is a TF placeholder. The value of the numpy array is fed into `y_true` during model fitting.

Comment: But if `y_train` is fed into the placeholder, their dimensions should agree

Comment: They will. You're probably testing in a wrong way. See my edit for a way to test if the values are equal.

Comment: @tiao You're totally right. Since the answer cannot be deleted, I've rewritten the answer to provide another way to do it.

Comment: @Lemon Sorry for a bad answer. Please see if the new answer works.

Comment: @Yu-Yang Does this solution work with fit_generator? And In order to get access to validation data within custom callback?

Comment: Yes, they are basically the same. Validation data is just `self.validation_data` in callbacks.

Comment: Is it possible to also get information about the inputs?

Comment: @Yu-Yang is it possible to access the whole `inputs` and `outputs` without having to specify e.g. `outputs[0]`. Something like `tf.assign(cbk.outputs, model.outputs, validate_shape=False)` ?

Comment: I'm not aware of one. Maybe a for loop can be used to build up the `fetches` list and the `tf.Variable`s to reduce duplicate code?

Comment: @Yu-Yang This method does not appear to work after loading a ModelCheckpoint. `K.eval(self.var_y_pred)` and `K.eval(self.var_y_true)` both evaluate to 0.0. Any ideas?

Comment: For those that run into the same problem as my comment above, you want to set `model.train_function = None` after loading the model, and after setting `model._function_kwargs = {'fetches': fetches}`, but before `model.fit()`, because `model._function_kwargs` values are not saved in the checkpoint. `model.fit()`  "reloads" this if `model.train_function = None`. For more details, check out the `_make_train_function` function in `training.py`

Comment: Also, `model.train_function = None` in the `compile` method of the `class Model` in training.py below `handle_metrics` in `keras/keras/engine/training.py`. So, setting method `model.train_function=None` , after compile, doesn't change anything.

Comment: I have tried this solution; however, I have got a problem in feeding the values
"   c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_1_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
  [[{{node dense_1_target}}]]". My last layer is softmax and I am using fit not fit_generator, any idea ?

Comment: Is there an alternative to the `fetches` that works with eager mode in TF2? It seems the eager TF2 training loop ignores the `fetches`, and I have no idea how to run them in the context of the training loop...

Comment: Your answer works find in TF1.15.0, by the way - you only need to add `import numpy as np; from keras.layers import Dense; from keras.models import Sequential`.

Comment: You should update this answer to the latest version of TF (2.1) and Keras.

Comment: It seems like there's already an answer that works in TF2 (sadly I don't have much experience with TF2). I'll just edit my answer to link to the up-to-date answer provided by @bers.

Answer (score 9):

**Long** edit (almost a new answer) for the following reasons:

- [Yu-Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531463/yu-yang)'s 2017 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47081613/880783) relies on the private `_make_train_function` and `_function_kwargs` APIs, which work only in TF1 (and maybe in TF1 compatibility, so-called non-eager mode).
- Similarly, [Binyan Hu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9501820/binyan-hu)'s 2020 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59926666/880783) relies on `_make_test_function` and does not work in TF2 by default (requiring non-eager mode as well).
- My own Jan 2020 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59697739/880783), which was already subject to several required configuration settings, seems to have stopped working with (or before) TF 2.5, and I was not able to make `model.inputs` or `model.outputs` work any longer.
- Finally, the earlier version of this answer requires potentially expensive model evaluation to obtain the predictions for each batch. A similar solution [to obtain activation histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60816678/how-does-one-log-activations-using-tf-keras-callbacks-tensorboard#comment109914454_60816678) even led to OOM issues with repeated training of different models.

So I set out find a way to obtain all possible quantities (inputs, targets, predictions, activations), *batch-wise*, without using any private APIs. The aim was to be able to call `.numpy()` on the intended quantities, so Keras callbacks can run ordinary Python code to ease debugging (I suppose that is what this question is mainly about - for maximum performance, one would probably try to integrate as many computations as possible into TensorFlow's graph operations anyway).

This is the common base model for all solutions:

```py
"""Demonstrate batch data access."""
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


class DataCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    """This class is where all implementations differ."""


def tf_nan(dtype):
    """Create NaN variable of proper dtype and variable shape for assign()."""
    return tf.Variable(float("nan"), dtype=dtype, shape=tf.TensorShape(None))


def main():
    """Run main."""
    model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(2,))])

    callback = DataCallback()

    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
    model.fit(
        x=tf.transpose(tf.range(7.0) + [[0.2], [0.4]]),
        y=tf.transpose(tf.range(7.0) + 10 + [[0.5]]),
        validation_data=(
            tf.transpose(tf.range(11.0) + 30 + [[0.6], [0.7]]),
            tf.transpose(tf.range(11.0) + 40 + [[0.9]]),
        ),
        shuffle=False,
        batch_size=3,
        epochs=2,
        verbose=0,
        callbacks=[callback],
    )
    model.save("tmp.tf")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The following three snippets show one possible solution each, each with their own pros and cons. The core trick is always the same: allocate a `tf.Variable` and use `tf.Variable.assign` to export the intended quantity, from some Keras code run in graph mode, into the callback. The methods differ slightly in callback initialization and (in one case) model compilation, and most importantly, in the quantities they can access, which is why I summarize them above each snippet.

---

#### Custom metric

Using a custom (fake) metric (similar to my Jan 2020 answer), while we cannot seem to access `model.inputs` nor `model.outputs` any more (and `model.(_)targets` does not even exist any longer), we *can* access `y_true` and `y_pred`, which represent the model targets and outputs:

```
[ ] Inputs/Samples (x)
[ ] Weights (w)
[+] Targets/Labels (y_true)
[+] Outputs/Predictions (y_pred)
[ ] All layers (or only final input/output layers)
```

```py
"""Demonstrate batch data access using a custom metric."""
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


class DataCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):  # diff
    """Callback to operate on batch data from metric."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Offer a metric to access batch data."""
        super().__init__()

        self.y_true = None
        self.y_pred = None

    def set_model(self, model):
        """Initialize variables when model is set."""
        self.y_true = tf_nan(model.output.dtype)
        self.y_pred = tf_nan(model.output.dtype)

    def metric(self, y_true, y_pred):
        """Fake metric."""
        self.y_true.assign(y_true)
        self.y_pred.assign(y_pred)

        return 0

    def on_train_batch_end(self, _batch, _logs=None):
        """See keras.callbacks.Callback.on_train_batch_end."""
        print("y_true =", self.y_true.numpy())
        print("y_pred =", self.y_pred.numpy())

    def on_train_end(self, _logs=None):
        """Clean up."""
        del self.y_true, self.y_pred


def tf_nan(dtype):
    """Create NaN variable of proper dtype and variable shape for assign()."""
    return tf.Variable(float("nan"), dtype=dtype, shape=tf.TensorShape(None))


def main():
    """Run main."""
    model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(2,))])

    callback = DataCallback()

    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam", metrics=[callback.metric])  # diff
    model.fit(
        x=tf.transpose(tf.range(7.0) + [[0.2], [0.4]]),
        y=tf.transpose(tf.range(7.0) + 10 + [[0.5]]),
        validation_data=(
            tf.transpose(tf.range(11.0) + 30 + [[0.6], [0.7]]),
            tf.transpose(tf.range(11.0) + 40 + [[0.9]]),
        ),
        shuffle=False,
        batch_size=3,
        epochs=2,
        verbose=0,
        callbacks=[callback],
    )
    model.save("tmp.tf")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

#### Custom training step

A custom training step is what I used in an earlier version of this answer. The idea still works in principle, but `y_pred` can be expensive and it might make sense to use a custom metric (see above) if that is required.

```
[+] Inputs/Samples (x)
[+] Weights (w)
[+] Targets/Labels (y_true)
[~] Outputs/Predictions (y_pred) [expensive!]
[ ] All layers (or only final input/output layers)
```

```py
"""Demonstrate batch data access using a custom training step."""
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


class DataCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):  # diff
    """Callback to operate on batch data from training step."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize tf.Variables."""
        super().__init__()

        self.x = None
        self.w = None
        self.y_true = None
        self.y_pred = None

    def set_model(self, model):
        """Wrap the model.train_step function to access training batch data."""
        self.x = tf_nan(model.input.dtype)
        # pylint:disable=protected-access (replace by proper dtype if you know it)
        if model.compiled_loss._user_loss_weights is not None:
            self.w = tf_nan(model.compiled_loss._user_loss_weights.dtype)
        self.y_true = tf_nan(model.output.dtype)
        self.y_pred = tf_nan(model.output.dtype)

        model_train_step = model.train_step

        def outer_train_step(data):
            # https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.7.0/keras/engine/training.py
            x, y_true, w = keras.utils.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(data)

            self.x.assign(x)
            if w is not None:
                self.w.assign(w)
            self.y_true.assign(y_true)

            result = model_train_step(data)

            y_pred = model(x)
            self.y_pred.assign(y_pred)

            return result

        model.train_step = outer_train_step

    def on_train_batch_end(self, _batch, _logs=None):
        """See keras.callbacks.Callback.on_train_batch_end."""
        print("x =", self.x.numpy())
        if self.w is not None:
            print("w =", self.w.numpy())
        print("y_true =", self.y_true.numpy())
        print("y_pred =", self.y_pred.numpy())

    def on_train_end(self, _logs=None):
        """Clean up."""
        del self.x, self.w, self.y_true, self.y_pred


def tf_nan(dtype):
    """Create NaN variable of proper dtype and variable shape for assign()."""
    return tf.Variable(float("nan"), dtype=dtype, shape=tf.TensorShape(None))


def main():
    """Run main."""
    model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(2,))])

    callback = DataCallback()

    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
    model.fit(
        x=tf.transpose(tf.range(7.0) + [[0.2], [0.4]]),
        y=tf.transpose(tf.range(7.0) + 10 + [[0.5]]),
        validation_data=(
            tf.transpose(tf.range(11.0) + 30 + [[0.6], [0.7]]),
            tf.transpose(tf.range(11.0) + 40 + [[0.9]]),
        ),
        shuffle=False,
        batch_size=3,
        epochs=2,
        verbose=0,
        callbacks=[callback],
    )
    model.save("tmp.tf")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

#### Custom layer call

A custom layer call is a super-flexible way of accessing each layer's inputs and outputs. The callback handles patching of the `call` functions for a list of layers. While we cannot access weights and targets (as these quantitities do not make sense at the level of individual layers), it allows us to access individual layer activations, which can be handy for questions such as [How does one log activations using `tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60816678).

```
[+] Inputs/Samples (x)
[ ] Weights (w)
[ ] Targets/Labels (y_true)
[+] Outputs/Predictions (y_pred)
[+] All layers (or only final input/output layers)
```

```py
"""Demonstrate batch data access using custom layer calls."""
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


class DataCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):  # diff
    """Callback to operate on batch data from selected (to be wrapped) layers."""

    def __init__(self, layers):
        """Wrap the calls of an iterable of model layers to access layer batch data."""
        super().__init__()

        self.data = {}
        self.inner_calls = {}
        self.outer_calls = {}

        for layer in layers:
            self.data[layer] = {
                "inputs": tf_nan(layer.input.dtype),
                "outputs": tf_nan(layer.output.dtype),
            }

            self.inner_calls[layer] = layer.call

            def outer_call(inputs, layer=layer, layer_call=layer.call):
                self.data[layer]["inputs"].assign(inputs)
                outputs = layer_call(inputs)
                self.data[layer]["outputs"].assign(outputs)
                return outputs

            self.outer_calls[layer] = outer_call

    def on_train_batch_begin(self, _epoch, _logs=None):
        """Wrap layer calls during each batch."""
        for layer, call in self.outer_calls.items():
            layer.call = call

    def on_train_batch_end(self, _epoch, _logs=None):
        """Restore original layer calls for ModelCheckpoint, model.save, ..."""
        for layer, call in self.inner_calls.items():
            layer.call = call

        for layer, data in self.data.items():
            print("Layer =", layer)
            print("Inputs =", data["inputs"].numpy())
            print("Outputs =", data["outputs"].numpy())


def tf_nan(dtype):
    """Create NaN variable of proper dtype and variable shape for assign()."""
    return tf.Variable(float("nan"), dtype=dtype, shape=tf.TensorShape(None))


def main():
    """Run main."""
    model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(2,))])

    callback = DataCallback(model.layers)  # diff

    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
    model.fit(
        x=tf.transpose(tf.range(7.0) + [[0.2], [0.4]]),
        y=tf.transpose(tf.range(7.0) + 10 + [[0.5]]),
        validation_data=(
            tf.transpose(tf.range(11.0) + 30 + [[0.6], [0.7]]),
            tf.transpose(tf.range(11.0) + 40 + [[0.9]]),
        ),
        shuffle=False,
        batch_size=3,
        epochs=2,
        verbose=0,
        callbacks=[callback],
    )
    model.save("tmp.tf")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

#### When to use which and open to-dos

I think the snippets above each solution nicely summarize what each approach is capable of. Generally,

- a custom training step will be ideal to access the model input, such as batched dataset generators, effects of shuffling, etc;
- a custom layer call is ideal to access the in-betweens of the model; and
- a custom metric is ideal to access the outputs of the model.

I am fairly certain (but have not tried) that one can combine all approaches to be able to access all batch quantities simultaneously. I have not tested anything but training mode - each method can have further pros and cons relating to their usefulness in testing or prediction mode. Finally, I assume, but have not tested either, that their should be only minor differences between `tf.keras` and `keras`. Having tested this code on TF2.8.rc1 and Keras 2.8.0, which has moved the `tf.keras` code back into the `keras` pip package, and not using any private APIs, I believe this assumption is justified.

It would be great if this approach could be extended to access `model.inputs` and `model.outputs` again. Currently, I am getting errors such as this one:

> TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(...), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.

---

#### Previous answer

From TF 2.2 on, you can use custom training steps rather than callbacks to achieve what you want. Here's a demo that works with `tensorflow==2.2.0rc1`, using inheritance to improve the `keras.Sequential` model. Performance-wise, this is not ideal as predictions are made twice, once in `self(x, training=True)` and once in `super().train_step(data)`. But you get the idea.

This works in eager mode and does not use private APIs, so it should be pretty stable. One caveat is that you have to use `tf.keras` (standalone `keras` does not support `Model.train_step`), but I feel standalone `keras` is becoming more and more deprecated anyway. (In fact, `tf.keras` migrates to `keras` in TF2.8.)

```py
"""Demonstrate access to Keras batch tensors in a tf.keras custom training step."""
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import data_adapter

in_shape = (2,)
out_shape = (1,)
batch_size = 3
n_samples = 7


class SequentialWithPrint(keras.Sequential):
    def train_step(self, original_data):
        # Basically copied one-to-one from https://git.io/JvDTv
        data = data_adapter.expand_1d(original_data)
        x, y_true, w = data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(data)
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)

        # this is pretty much like on_train_batch_begin
        K.print_tensor(w, "Sample weight (w) =")
        K.print_tensor(x, "Batch input (x) =")
        K.print_tensor(y_true, "Batch output (y_true) =")
        K.print_tensor(y_pred, "Prediction (y_pred) =")

        result = super().train_step(original_data)

        # add anything here for on_train_batch_end-like behavior

        return result


# Model
model = SequentialWithPrint([keras.layers.Dense(out_shape[0], input_shape=in_shape)])
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")

# Example data
X = np.random.rand(n_samples, *in_shape)
Y = np.random.rand(n_samples, *out_shape)

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=batch_size)
print("X: ", X)
print("Y: ", Y)
```

Finally, here is a simpler example without inheritance:

```py
"""Demonstrate access to Keras batch tensors in a tf.keras custom training step."""
import tensorflow as tf

IN_SHAPE = (2,)
OUT_SHAPE = (1,)
BATCH_SIZE = 3
N_SAMPLES = 7


def make_print_data_and_train_step(keras_model):
    """Return a train_step function that prints data batches."""
    original_train_step = keras_model.train_step

    def print_data_and_train_step(data):
        # Adapted from https://git.io/JvDTv, skipping data_adapter.expand_1d
        x, y_true, w = tf.keras.utils.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(data)
        y_pred = keras_model(x, training=True)

        # this is pretty much like on_train_batch_begin
        tf.keras.backend.print_tensor(w, "Sample weight (w) =")
        tf.keras.backend.print_tensor(x, "Batch input (x) =")
        tf.keras.backend.print_tensor(y_true, "Batch output (y_true) =")
        tf.keras.backend.print_tensor(y_pred, "Prediction (y_pred) =")

        result = original_train_step(data)

        # add anything here for on_train_batch_end-like behavior

        return result

    return print_data_and_train_step


# Model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(OUT_SHAPE[0], input_shape=IN_SHAPE)])
model.train_step = make_print_data_and_train_step(model)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")

# Example data
X = tf.random.normal((N_SAMPLES, *IN_SHAPE))
Y = tf.random.normal((N_SAMPLES, *OUT_SHAPE))

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
print("X: ", X)
print("Y: ", Y)
```

Comment: how to use a functional model instead?

Comment: @sK500 my question is several pages long. Care to explain in which code example you want to use a functional models and what prevents you from doing that?

Comment: first snippet under `custom metric`, I change `Sequential` to `Model` and I get      `self.y_true = tf_nan(model.output.dtype)
AttributeError: Layer model has no inbound nodes.. Did you mean: 'outputs'?`

Comment: @sK500 I cannot test this on my phone, but `model.output` seems to be used only in `tf_nan` and only to get a `dtype`. Have you tried another way to get the `dtype` - if all else fails, hardcoding something like `tf.float32`?

Comment: What about using GradientTape? The solutions using callbacks look overly complex.

Comment: @JussiKujala feel free to add your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** This approach has stopped working. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60787957/880783) a number of solutions compatible with TF2.8 (and hopefully beyond).

One problem with @Yu-Yang's solution is that it relies on `model._function_kwargs`, which is not guaranteed to work as it is not part of the API. In particular, in TF2 with eager execution, session kwargs seem to be either not accepted at all or run preemptively due to eager mode.

Therefore, here is my solution tested on `tensorflow==2.1.0`. The trick is to replace `fetches` by a Keras metric, in which the assignment operations from `fetches` are made during training.

This even enables a Keras-only solution if the batch size divides the number of samples; otherwise, another trick has to be applied when initializing TensorFlow variables with a `None` shape, similar to `validate_shape=False` in earlier solutions (compare https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35667).

Importantly, `tf.keras` behaves differently from `keras` (sometimes just ignoring assignments, or seeing variables as Keras symbolic tensors), so this updated solution takes care of both implementations (`Keras==2.3.1` and `tensorflow==2.1.0`).

```
"""Demonstrate access to Keras symbolic tensors in a (tf.)keras.Callback."""

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

use_tf_keras = True
if use_tf_keras:
    from tensorflow import keras
    from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

    tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(False)
    compile_kwargs = {"run_eagerly": False, "experimental_run_tf_function": False}

else:
    import keras
    from keras import backend as K

    compile_kwargs = {}


in_shape = (2,)
out_shape = (1,)
batch_size = 3
n_samples = 7


class CollectKerasSymbolicTensorsCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    """Collect Keras symbolic tensors."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize intermediate variables for batches and lists."""
        super().__init__()

        # Collect batches here
        self.inputs = []
        self.targets = []
        self.outputs = []

        # # For a pure Keras solution, we need to know the shapes beforehand;
        # # in particular, batch_size must divide n_samples:
        # self.input = K.variable(np.empty((batch_size, *in_shape)))
        # self.target = K.variable(np.empty((batch_size, *out_shape)))
        # self.output = K.variable(np.empty((batch_size, *out_shape)))

        # If the shape of these variables will change (e.g., last batch), initialize
        # arbitrarily and specify `shape=tf.TensorShape(None)`:
        self.input = tf.Variable(0.0, shape=tf.TensorShape(None))
        self.target = tf.Variable(0.0, shape=tf.TensorShape(None))
        self.output = tf.Variable(0.0, shape=tf.TensorShape(None))

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        """Evaluate the variables and save them into lists."""
        self.inputs.append(K.eval(self.input))
        self.targets.append(K.eval(self.target))
        self.outputs.append(K.eval(self.output))

    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        """Print all variables."""
        print("Inputs: ", *self.inputs)
        print("Targets: ", *self.targets)
        print("Outputs: ", *self.outputs)


@tf.function
def assign_keras_symbolic_tensors_metric(_foo, _bar):
    """
    Return the assignment operations as a metric to have them evaluated by Keras.

    This replaces `fetches` from the TF1/non-eager-execution solution.
    """
    # Collect assignments as list of (dest, src)
    assignments = (
        (callback.input, model.inputs[0]),
        (callback.target, model._targets[0] if use_tf_keras else model.targets[0]),
        (callback.output, model.outputs[0]),
    )
    for (dest, src) in assignments:
        dest.assign(src)

    return 0


callback = CollectKerasSymbolicTensorsCallback()
metrics = [assign_keras_symbolic_tensors_metric]

# Example model
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(out_shape[0], input_shape=in_shape)])
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam", metrics=metrics, **compile_kwargs)

# Example data
X = np.random.rand(n_samples, *in_shape)
Y = np.random.rand(n_samples, *out_shape)

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=[callback])
print("X: ", X)
print("Y: ", Y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the way tf.keras.callbacks.TesnsorBoard saves v1 (graph) summaries.

No variable assignments and no redundant metrics.

For use with tensorflow>=2.0.0, graph (disable eager) mode during evaluating.

Extensive operations on the numpy predictions can be implemented by overriding `SavePrediction._pred_callback`.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

in_shape = (2,)
out_shape = (1,)
batch_size = 2
n_samples = 32


class SavePrediction(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._get_pred = None
        self.preds = []

    def _pred_callback(self, preds):
        self.preds.append(preds)

    def set_model(self, model):
        super().set_model(model)
        if self._get_pred is None:
            self._get_pred = self.model.outputs[0]

    def on_test_begin(self, logs):
        # pylint: disable=protected-access
        self.model._make_test_function()
        # pylint: enable=protected-access
        if self._get_pred not in self.model.test_function.fetches:
            self.model.test_function.fetches.append(self._get_pred)
            self.model.test_function.fetch_callbacks[self._get_pred] = self._pred_callback

    def on_test_end(self, logs):
        if self._get_pred in self.model.test_function.fetches:
            self.model.test_function.fetches.remove(self._get_pred)
        if self._get_pred in self.model.test_function.fetch_callbacks:
            self.model.test_function.fetch_callbacks.pop(self._get_pred)

        print(self.preds)


model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(out_shape[0], input_shape=in_shape)
])
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")

X = np.random.rand(n_samples, *in_shape)
Y = np.random.rand(n_samples, *out_shape)

model.evaluate(X, Y,
               batch_size=batch_size,
               callbacks=[SavePrediction()])
```

Comment: Is `_make_test_function` documented somewhere? This looks like another private API that is uncertain to remain in the codebase for long... (Same question for `fetches`, I guess.) I think this works only because internally, `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` switches over **a lot** of things to `v1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to save the target and prediction using a callback. I think other answers either are old or over complicated. But with the latest keras API, this is fairly easy and logically achievable. Let's do this step by step.

Let's first start with a very common setup.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32,))
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam", loss="mse", metrics=["mae"], run_eagerly=0
)

x = np.random.random((1000, 32))
y = np.random.random((1000, 1))

model.fit(
    x,
    y,
    epochs=5,
    batch_size=512,
)

loss, score = model.evaluate(
    x, y, batch_size=256
)
loss, score
(0.4762837588787079, 0.5724010467529297)
```

Here, with [`model.evaluate`](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) we are passing 256 batches of samples and eventually get the final loss and scores. To receive the target and prediction, either in **training** time or **evaluation** time, or **prediction** time, we can leverage the following features:

1. [Overriding the `fit` method.](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/)
2. [Callback](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/)

If we look at the [training API](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/), we will see that it has a `callback` argument. So, the ideas are,

1. We will store data by overriding the training method(s).
2. We will receive these data and reset the placeholder variable by using the callback.

This may sound overwhelming but it's pretty straightforward. Let's see in the code. First, we will write some placeholder variables which will store data (`x`, `y`, or `y_pred`).

```py
from tensorflow.experimental import numpy as tnp
# CPU: Important if tf.config.optimizer.set_jit(True)
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
    # for input
    val_x = tf.Variable(
        tnp.empty((0, 32), dtype=tf.float32), shape=[None, 32]
        )
    # for target
    val_gt = tf.Variable(
        tnp.empty((0, 1), dtype=tf.float32), shape=[None, 1]
        )
    # for prediction
    val_pred = tf.Variable(
        tnp.empty((0, 1), dtype=tf.float32), shape=[None, 1]
        )
```

Now, we will override the `keras.Model.evaluate` method and use the above variables to store data. Please note, for demonstration purposes, I am using the `evaluation` method but it can be extended for the other training method, i.e., training and prediction.

```py
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, model, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=model.name, **kwargs)
        self.model = model 

    def train_step(): # override training step

    def predict_step(): # override prediction step

    def test_step(self, data):
        x, y = data
        y_pred = self.model(x, training=False)
        self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)

        val_x.assign(
            tf.concat([val_x, x], axis=0)
        )
        val_gt.assign(
            tf.concat([val_gt, y], axis=0)
        )
        val_pred.assign(
            tf.concat([val_pred, y_pred], axis=0)
        )
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

Let's now create a [custom callback](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/). We will override the `def on_test_batch_begin` to reset the above placeholders (`val_x`, `val_gt`, `val_pred`) and `on_test_batch_end` methods to receive the values from the above placeholders.

```py
class MyCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_test_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
        # reset collectors [val_x, val_gt, val_pred]
        val_x.assign(
            tf.Variable((
                tnp.empty((0, 32), dtype=tf.float32)), shape=[None, 32]
            )
        )
        val_gt.assign(
            tf.Variable(
                tnp.empty((0, 1), dtype=tf.float32), shape=[None, 1]
            )
        )
        val_pred.assign(
            tf.Variable(
                tnp.empty((0, 1), dtype=tf.float32), shape=[None, 1]
            )
        )

    def on_test_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        # save collectors [val_x, val_gt, val_pred]
        gt_pred = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "gt": [i for j in val_gt.numpy() for i in j],
                'pred': [i for j in val_pred.numpy() for i in j]
            }
        )
        gt_pred.to_csv(f'gt_pred_batch_{batch}.csv', index=False)
        np.save(f'val_x_batch_{batch}', val_x.numpy())
```

Now, we will extend our previous model so that it can be used with callback.

```py
extended_model = CustomModel(model)
extended_model.compile(
    optimizer="adam", loss="mse", metrics=["mae"], run_eagerly=0
)

# x.shape # (1000, 32)
loss, score = extended_model.evaluate(
    x, y, batch_size=256, callbacks=MyCallback()
)
12ms/step - loss: 0.4763 - mae: 0.5724
```

With `len(x) == 1000` and batch size `256`, we expect to see around 4 saved files.

```py
batch_0 = pd.read_csv('/content/gt_pred_batch_0.csv')
batch_1 = pd.read_csv('/content/gt_pred_batch_1.csv')
batch_2 = pd.read_csv('/content/gt_pred_batch_2.csv')
batch_3 = pd.read_csv('/content/gt_pred_batch_3.csv')

batch_0.shape, batch_1.shape, batch_2.shape, batch_3.shape
((256, 2), (256, 2), (256, 2), (232, 2))

(
    len(batch_0) + len(batch_1) + 
    len(batch_2) + len(batch_3) == len(x)
)
True
```

```py
batch_0123 = pd.concat(
    [
        batch_0, batch_1, batch_2, batch_3
    ]
)
batch_0123.shape
(1000, 2)

m = keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError() 
m.update_state(
    batch_0123['gt'].tolist(),
    batch_0123['pred'].tolist(), 
)
m.result().numpy() # 0.47628376

m = keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError() 
m.update_state(
    batch_0123['gt'].tolist(),
    batch_0123['pred'].tolist(), 
)
m.result().numpy() # 5724011
```

That's it. We save raw input in `npy` format and targets + predictions as a pandas data frame.

---

Note

- [Full code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1U9uCMr40gen9miu2Zzchm0uDmcLAkVXY?usp=sharing).
- This method can be extended for training data set in training time.
- This method can be extended for other [callback methods](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/).
- We have collected the data (raw input, target, and prediction) after training is done, but this is also possible during the training time. If you can use **callback** and **8override the training methods** at a time, you can achieve this.
- This code works CPU, single-GPU, and multi-GPU. But it won't work on the [TPU device](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/59511).
- I opened an issue to have these features by default. If you feel the same, raise a voice. [Ticket](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/17350).
- The above code is also tested in the [`keras-core` API](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-core) that supports multi-backend framework, TensorFlow, Jax, and PyTorch.