# Keras costum Callback. When generating precision recall I get an error in _flow_index

Tags: python, callback, keras, precision

I'm training a binary classifier using Keras. I want to generate the precision_score and recall_score after each epoch in order to analyze the training more in depth. On the internet I found tutorials/help, such as:

- https://medium.com/@thongonary/how-to-compute-f1-score-for-each-epoch-in-keras-a1acd17715a2
- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2607

I found [Accessing validation data within a custom callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676248/accessing-validation-data-within-a-custom-callback) which worked best for me since I'm using Keras fit_generator. It managed to compute precision and recall after each epoch. However, I think I do something wrong when creating the custom Callback. I get the following error message:

```
File "...\envs\keras\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 845, in _flow_index
current_index = (self.batch_index * self.batch_size) % self.n

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

My best guess is that the custom Callback inherits incorrectly from Keras.

Has anybody experienced this issue?
Or do anyone know what I am missing?

**UPDATE**

I think I understand the error now. In Keras image.py *current_index* is divided by *self.n*. In the class named Iterator (in Keras) *n* is defined as

> n: Integer, total number of samples in the dataset to loop over.

In other words, I understand it as that the network can't be fed with zero samples. I realized that my test set was empty (0 samples), hence the error message.

When corrected (fed the test set with data) the code worked fine :)

Comment: Please note, my data set is split into three subsets; training, validation and test sets. The training and validation set is used when training. The test set, which is a much smaller set, I use to test how well the network performs after the training is complete.

Comment: Yes, but it still doesnt explain why the error occurs.