# How can i see validation accuracy ONLY at the last 3 epochs ? This is for reducing time

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am working on cifar10 dataset with Resnet18 architecture. My need is now to reach 94 accuracy within 100 secs. 
So i have been advised to check validation accuracy only for the last 3 epochs. Anyone help me how to do that ?

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint,LearningRateScheduler

model.fit_generator(generator=gen,
   steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(50000/512),
   epochs=24,
   validation_data=validation_iterator, 
   verbose=1,
   callbacks =[olr])
```

The above code checks validation accuracy for all 24 epochs, but i want to check ONLY for last 3 epochs.

Comment: Have you tried something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54897630/2424980 ? Have an own callback and only do validation if `epoch > your_desired_number`

Comment: The idea of looking validation accuray mostly is yo see if your model overfit or not. With just 3 epochs of 24 you cant see that.

Comment: @L3n95. it still not working. from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

class MetricsCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if epoch>2:
            predictions = self.model.evaluate_generator(validation_iterator, steps = len(validation_iterator))
            #print('r2:', r2_score(prediction, y_test).round(2)) model.fit_generator(generator=gen,steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(50000/512), epochs=4, 
                                validation_data = validation_iterator,verbose=1,callbacks =[MetricsCallback()])

Comment: Please do **not** use the comments space to provide code - it is literally unreadable! Edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may break training into two separate phases in the latter you provide validation data:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=gen,
   steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(50000/512),
   epochs=21,
   verbose=1,
   callbacks =[olr])

model.fit_generator(generator=gen,
   steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(50000/512),
   epochs=24,
   validation_data=validation_iterator, 
   verbose=1,
   callbacks =[olr],
   initial_epoch=21)
```