# Keras - Callback to calculate variance

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, callback, keras

Is there a possibility to calculate the variance of target values for each batch using keras custom callback?

Maybe in a similar manner to the [Create keras callback to save model predictions and targets for each batch during training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079111/create-keras-callback-to-save-model-predictions-and-targets-for-each-batch-durin) ?
Im using keras from tensorflow backend and python3.

Cheers,

Maks

Comment: Tensorflow.keras tutorial describes how to write a custom keras callback function. Find more detail here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback. Thanks!