# Early Stopping with a Cross-Validated Metric in Keras

Tags: python, keras, prediction, cross-validation

Is there a way in Keras to cross-validate the early stopping metric being monitored `EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_acc', patience = 5)`? Before allowing training to proceed to the next epoch, could the model be cross-validated to get a more robust estimate of the test error? What I have found is that the early stopping metric, say the accuracy on a validation set, can suffer from high variance. Early-stopped models often do not perform nearly as well on unseen data, and I suspect this is because of the high variance associated with the validation set approach.

To minimize the variance in the early stopping metric, I would like to k-fold cross-validate the early stopping metric as the model trains from epoch `i` to epoch `i + 1`. I would like to take the model at epoch `i`, divide the training data into 10 parts, learn on 9 parts, estimate the error on the remaining part, repeat so that all 10 parts have had a chance to be the validation set, and then proceed with training to epoch `i + 1` with the full training data as usual. The average of the 10 error estimates will hopefully be a more robust metric that can be used for early stopping.

I have tried to write a custom metric function that includes k-fold cross-validation but I can't get it to work. Is there a way to cross-validate the early stopping metric being monitored, perhaps through a custom function inside the Keras model or a loop outside the Keras model?

Thanks!!

Comment: What you want to do seems very costly though.

Answer (score 3):

Keras really does have a greatly customizable callback functionality as can be seen 
[here](https://keras.io/callbacks/).

If you are not satisfied with keras current `EarlyStopping` function, which for me does the work of checking the validation loss during training, you could create a custom callback function. Also custom callback functions can be chained.

If your issue is accessing the model inside the callback, then `self` is the variable you want to access as can be seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079111/create-keras-callback-to-save-model-predictions-and-targets-for-each-batch-durin). I don't completely understand why you want to "redevelop" the model during test phase. BUT then with that, you could still use callbacks, after the `EarlyStopping` callback, you could create another callback function that could "redevelop" the model.

If you want to access the models deeper variables you could use, Keras [backend](https://keras.io/backend/).

I hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks!! You are right, "re-develop" was a poor choice; I have edited my question to hopefully make what I would like to do clearer. The links you have suggested are helpful but I am not a great programmer, so could you post some code that would illustrate what you mean and help me get started?

Comment: hmm the link I gave you has sample code already on how to create and use callbacks for keras. you could also search lot on samples online. :)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that using a callback as suggested by @VincentPakson would be cleaner and more efficient, but the level of programming required is beyond me. I was able to create a for loop to do what I wanted by:

1. Training a model for a single epoch and saving it using `model.save()`.
2. Loading the saved model and training the model for a single epoch for each of the 10 folds (i.e. 10 models), then averaging the 10 validation set errors.
3. Loading the saved model and training for a single epoch using all of the training data, and the overwriting the saved model with this model.
4. Repeating steps 1-3 until the estimate from 2 stops improving for a given patience.

I'd love a better answer but this seems to work. Slowly.

Comment: you can put this in your question you know and just specify this as an edit to it. Some might add more input to this.