# tf.assign doesn't update tf.Variable value in custom callback init constructor using model._function_kwargs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback

I need to create a custom callback to get the target values i.e, y_true and y_pred (predicted values). So, I read the post :[Create keras callback to save model predictions and targets for each batch during training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079111/create-keras-callback-to-save-model-predictions-and-targets-for-each-batch-durin)

And created my callback the same as they created in the answer

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

class CollectOutputAndTarget(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CollectOutputAndTarget, self).__init__()
        self.targets = []  # collect y_true batches
        self.outputs = []  # collect y_pred batches

        # the shape of these 2 variables will change according to batch shape
        # to handle the "last batch", specify `validate_shape=False`
        self.var_y_true = tf.Variable(0., validate_shape=False)
        self.var_y_pred = tf.Variable(0., validate_shape=False)

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        # evaluate the variables and save them into lists
        self.targets.append(K.eval(self.var_y_true))
        self.outputs.append(K.eval(self.var_y_pred))

# build a simple model
# have to compile first for model.targets and model.outputs to be prepared
model = Sequential([Dense(5, input_shape=(10,))])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

# initialize the variables and the `tf.assign` ops
cbk = CollectOutputAndTarget()
fetches = [tf.assign(cbk.var_y_true, model.targets[0], validate_shape=False),
           tf.assign(cbk.var_y_pred, model.outputs[0], validate_shape=False)]
model._function_kwargs = {'fetches': fetches}  # use `model._function_kwargs` if using `Model` instead of `Sequential`
```

When I add `on_epoch_end` and try to print the value of `self.targets`.
I get arrays of 0s.
For `on_epoch_end` the code is as below:

```
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    print(self.targets)
```

My model is created using the functional API `Model` and has pretrained weights loaded into it, instead of Sequential. And after the compiling the model as `model.compile`, I instantiate the `callback` and create the `fetches` object and add it to `train_function` as follows:

```
cbk = CollectOutputAndTarget()
        
fetches = [tf.assign(cbk.var_y_true, model.targets[0], validate_shape=False),
                   tf.assign(cbk.var_y_pred, model.outputs[0], validate_shape=False)]
model._function_kwargs = {'fetches': fetches}
```

And, then I call `model.fit_generator` using my datagenerator. I am getting `0s` in `self.targets`, which shouldn't happen, if `var_y_true` and `var_y_pred` are getting updated with `model.targets` and `model.outputs` . Also, I don't understand that if we're already assigning the values for  `cbk.var_y_true` and `cbk.var_y_pred`, then why do we need to use `model._function_kwargs`?

I tried using `model.train_function = None` after setting the `fetches` and before calling `fit_generator`, but still I get the same result.

Comment: Have you found the main reason for this error?

Comment: @Yasmin: yes, I've found the solution, actually I was getting the values for the class ids, seems like yolo has y_true values as class_ids, instead of the box_coordinates.