# How to access batch data during Keras model training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm building a custom metric to train a neural network in Keras, but I would need to use the model developed at the end of each training batch to develop class predictions for that given batch.

The pipeline would look something like this:

1. Model training completed for Epoch 1 Batch 1
2. Collect predictions for Batch 1 using this model
3. Compute custom metric from these predictions
4. Repeat process from Epoch 1 Batch 2 and so on...

Is there any way I can find what data from my original training dataset has been put forward for each batch? I've tried using Keras backend functions and callbacks but the input layer is a symbolic tensor which can't read as raw data.

Some workarounds include setting the batch_size to be the whole training set, but that comes with a few computational problems and I'm worried it will affect training accuracy. I've also thought of predicting on another random batch that I have designed, but I'd rather gauge the performance of each model based on the batch it was originally modelled from.

Right now my callback function looks like this:

class CollectCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

```
def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    
    a =  self.model.predict(X)
    
    print(a)
```

but X is the whole training set. It would be great if I could extract the batch dataset and feed that into the predict model instead. Any way of doing this?

Comment: some pointer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76674353/9215780

Comment: Hi @Cam you can create a custom [callback](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/) in Keras to collect predictions for each batch during training. However, Keras does not directly provide access to the individual batches during training. One way to work around this limitation is to create a custom generator that yields both the batch data and the corresponding labels, then use this generator with the fit_generator() function